# Extract function signatures from the Office VBA Object Models?

Tags: vba, extract

Is there a way to extract function/property data from the Object Library binaries (eg, the Microsoft Access Object 14.0 Library which is typically located at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACC.OLB`)?

I'm not interested in the implementation details, I just want to be able to extract the public interfaces - something along the lines of:

```
Class: TextBox
    Properties:
         Property Get BackColor() As Long
         Property Let BackColor(value As Long)
         ... (etc)

    Functions:
         Sub Move(Left, [Top], [Width], [Height])
         ... (etc)

    Events:
         Event AfterUpdate()
         Event BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
         ... (etc)
```

**The exact formatting is not important** - I just need a text dump of this data in any format (I'll then write a program around it to parse it). In the C++ world this would essentially be an extract of the header files.

Presumably this is something the Object Explorer within the VBE already does (and the AutoComplete, and any other program capable of reading `*.olb` files), unfortunately I don't even know where to start here (Googling "extract from olb file" / "read olb file" hasn't yielded any useful results). Can anyone offer any advice with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do that with PowerShell. The syntax is:

```
New-Object -ComObject <com object>
```

To list all properties in `Excel.Application` we use `Get-Member`:

```
New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application | Get-member
```

To export the list in a text file:

```
New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application | Get-member | Format-Table -Wrap -Autosize | Out-File list.txt
```

---

### Edit:

COM Object are registered in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes`

```
get-ChildItem "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.*" | foreach-object {New-Object -ComObject $_.pschildname | Get-member | Format-Table -Wrap -Autosize | Out-File $($_.pschildName + ".txt") }
```

This command will list all COM Objects whose name starts with `Excel.` and print their respective properties in a file named `<com object>.txt`.

Comment: This is great, thanks. Is there a way to automate this for every Com Object in the library? ie `Excel.Application, Excel.Workbook, Excel.Chart` etc etc. There's about 300 of them, so doing it manually could take a while!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft had a utility called "oleview.exe" which was certainly available in year 2003. It can open a '.OLB' file file, and dump it in a text format. I have a copy of oleview and it still runs fine on Windows 10. It also needs a associated DLL called "iviewers.dll".  I don't know where it can be downloaded these days, so try Googling.  It may have been supplied with Visual Studio.

Comment: Oleview is available within the latest (v10) Windows SDK.